# Rails 3 - abandon sending mail within ActionMailer action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering how I could conditionally abandon sending mail within the action ActionMailer action itself.

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  ...

  def some_emails
    some_models = Model.where(:a => 1)
    if !some_models.blank?
      mail(...)
    else
      # What to add here?
      # render :nothing => true doesn't work
    end
  end

end
```

Now invoking this through `SomeMailer.some_emails.deliver!` returns an 
`ArgumentError: A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message`

Comment: Will you be sending one email for each model, or one email with a list of all models?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead put your conditions in the place where you are making the call to SomeMailer.some_emails.deliver!

Comment: Well - this is being called in a scheduler, not the best place to add conditions.

Comment: make call to something else in scheduler where you can give these conditions and from there make mail calls.

Answer (score 44):

Set perform_deliveries to false, like so:

```
emails = get_email_list_somehow
if emails.present?
  mail options.merge(:bcc => emails)
else
  self.message.perform_deliveries = false
end
```

This will quietly not try to send and should stop the error from happening.

Comment: +1 this solution works if your project cannot be refactored to make the decision to send the email outside of the Mailer class (e.g. for delayed jobs, cron jobs, etc).

Comment: I agree - this is a better solution.  Keep it DRY and do the check in one place.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The original question specified within the mailer, and this is the best solution within the mailer.

Comment: I agree. I was uneasy about this approach initially. However, there's an example right within the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3.2.9 you can finally conditionally call `mail()`. Here's the related [GitHub thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7761). Now the OP's code can be reworked like this:

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  ...

  def some_emails
    some_models = Model.where(:a => 1)
    unless some_models.blank?
      mail(...)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The strange thing is, that with Rails 3.1.rc4 and WEBrick, it works fine on my local WEBrick webserver. But as soon as I push to Heroku cedar stack, their WEBrick throws the

> ArgumentError: A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From)

You have to remove the conditional statements as stated in above answer. That fixes it so that it also works on Heroku, not just your local machine

Comment: Thanks to excellent Heroku support who replied quickly, i found out that i was wrong about my previous comment. If you run WEBrick in production mode locally, the same error appears. So its not an issue with Heroku but rather an inconsistency of local dev and production environments.

Comment: Please delete or update your post when you found out you where wrong. +1 for keeping other reads in mind!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  There is no real way to do it within the ActionMailer action so I did the following in my cron task:

```
 users.each do |user|
  begin
    UserMailer.event_second_reminder_group_user_email(user).deliver
    puts "  - sending reminder email to user #{user.email}"
  rescue
  end
end
puts "Complete!"
```

Now if an error is thrown, it doesn't break the app!

Comment: Putting a blank rescue is usually not recommended. I would only rescue the specific error which might be raised.